# How do I change color of text in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a Textview called myText defined in xml. The textview has an accompanying drawable which is actually a selector.

When the user clicks on the TextView I want to not only change the drawable, but also the color of the text. My code for effecting the change is below. The problem is only the drawable  is changing. The text is not changing. How do I fix this code so the text color changes as well?

**Inside activity**

```
if (R.color.my_red == myText.getCurrentTextColor()) {
        myText.setSelected(true);
        myText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_blue));
    } else {
        myText.setSelected(false);
        myText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_red));
    }
```

**selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/im_red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/im_blue"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I was comparing apples and oranges. The fix is to add `getResources().getColor` to the if clause.

```
if (getResources().getColor(R.color.my_red) == myText.getCurrentTextColor()) {
        myText.setSelected(true);
        myText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_blue));
    } else {
        myText.setSelected(false);
        myText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.my_red));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Color` class, for instance: `Color.RED`. Or if you have a HTML style color, you can even use: `.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))`

Comment: This essentially does the same as user3093402 is already doing. user3093402 just passes a color resource instead.

Comment: thanks for posting but I found the solution. see my response above.